# Connection refused on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, google-chrome, 18.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and i just installed the 18.10 version as a dual boot with windows. My problem is that when i try to connect to certain websites likes my university's mail, i get a `connection refused error` from chrome or firefox. Did i mess something up during the installation process? I cleaned the cache from the browsers but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add the exact message that each browser shows? I've never seed "connection refused error" message from Firefox - if you try to connect to a valid IP but invalid port you usually get an "Unable to connect" error.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused is typically related to a firewall rule actively blocking the connection as opposed to a network configuration error that might result in a connection timeout response.

It's quite possible something on your LAN is preventing access.  Is the IP assigned to your Linux environment the same as the IP assigned to your Windows environment?  If not, can you statically assign the same IP to both environments and test again.

Comment: How do i find that IP out? You mean my local IP e.g. 192.1...... ?

Comment: In Linux, open a terminal window and type " ifconfig -a "

In Windows, open a command prompt and type " ipconfig "

Both will show the IP address of the network interface.  If they are different, you can manually set the Linux one to the same as the Windows one.

If it works then, you can either contact your network administrator and let them know that your IP changes between environments, OR you can just statically assign both environments to a known working IP and move on.  Really just depends on what your network environment is like.

Comment: @Joey - I don't think you are right regarding firewall behavior: most firewall blocking rules drop packets (resulting in timeout) instead of returning ICMP "connection refused" errors - as this behavior is considered "reporting on the existence of a server" to an attacker.

Comment: @Joey thanks to your suggestion, when i run `ifconfig -a` on linux i was notified that there were no net tools installed. After installing them, boom fixed!

Comment: @Guss - I agree with your assessment, a properly configured, the firewall would have returned a connection timeout instead of a connection refused response.  In either case, I believe the user worked through the problem.